# Copying a MYSQL database folder

Tags: mysql, database

I have been using a MYSQL database in conjunction to a website I am making. I am going to hire someone to do specific work for me for content on the site, but they will need access to the database for testing. I have found where my database is stored (C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data). It is a folder of the database which contains all the table's data.

Can I just send this database folder, which contains all the tables, to whoever I hire? Would they be able to just paste it into their `data` folder and have access to it in their database?

If not, how can I share my database? (I want to give them a copy to test with, not have access to the one I'm using now)

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

Answer (score 0):

Last time when I was tested, it wasn't working. 
The best way is just create backup of your db and send it by email or put it on some resource like dropbox and share it with that person.